# Dynamic variable length inside a structure C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a structure for a data packet that has a dynamic payload length and is determined by a variable within the header struct (LEN).

I am unsure on how to do this properly and I am confused by some of the examples that i have come across. Bellow is the Structure that is the basis of what i will be using.
Thanks.

```
struct packet
{
    unsigned char payload;
    unsigned int CRC : 16;

    struct header
    {
        unsigned char SRC;
        unsigned char DST;
        unsigned char NS : 3;       //3 bits long
        unsigned char NR : 3;
        unsigned char RSV : 1;      //1 bit long
        unsigned char LST : 1;
        unsigned char OP;
        unsigned char LEN;
    } HEADER;

};

struct packet PACKET;
```

Comment: LEN will be changed each time a new packet is received, which then causes the payload to change each time dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the payload a pointer instead and allocate it at runtime according to the value of `LEN` in the header field.

Comment: LEN is changed by an incoming packet based off of how large that packet is going to be.

Comment: You would need to manually resize the payload whenever the header length changes. It will *not* be dynamically resized just based off of changing the header length.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a construct sometimes referred to as a "stretchy array".   (Or as @Jerry Coffin points out, a "flexible array member")  The variable-length payload needs to be at the end:

```
struct packet
{
    struct header
    {
        unsigned char SRC;
        unsigned char DST;
        unsigned char NS : 3;       //3 bits long
        unsigned char NR : 3;
        unsigned char RSV : 1;      //1 bit long
        unsigned char LST : 1;
        unsigned char OP;
        unsigned char LEN;
    } HEADER;
     unsigned int CRC : 16;
     unsigned char payload[1];  //STRETCHY.
};

struct packet PACKET;
```

This type of structure needs to be dynamically allocated, since you need to manually make enough room for the payload.

```
PACKET * p = malloc( sizeof(PACKET)+payloadLength*sizeof(char) );
p->HEADER->LEN = payloadLength;
//fill in rest of header here.
memcpy(p->payload, incomingData, payloadLength);
```

Comment: First time I've heard of "stretchy array". This is usually called the "struct hack", or (in C99) a "flexible array member". For a flexible array member, you don't include a subscript though, so it would be just `unsigned char payload[];`.

Comment: That's why I said "sometimes called".  I figured the nickname from my shop wasn't universal.   Also, I think the subscript was required pre-C99

Comment: I believe you're correct on all counts. I probably wouldn't have even brought it up, except to provide things for the OP to feed to Google, should s/he feel so inclined.

Comment: “Also, make a note of the term 'stretchy array'. I like it. I want to use it more often in conversation.” (apologies to General Melchett)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the length in your struct but not the data.  Depending on what you are doing  you handle the data differently.  The struct should probably contain a pointer to the data but you have to handle this when you serialize deserialize the struct.  That is the pointer will mean nothing when you read it back in.

So you write the struct out including the size of the data field, then the data field out. When you read it back you fscanf the struct, then read the size of bytes the struct tells you to from the stream and store that as your data, and then finally store a pointer to the newly read data in the struct that was created with fscanf.  If you are reading in multiple items like this you can continue at that point reading the next struct then data and so on.